# I want to fill a matrix using a loop returning the value of a function where the argumentof the function also change ith the loop

Tags: r, list, function, loops, matrix

**So here is my function :**

```
combination<-function(t,s,T,H,l) {
  
  for(i in 0:floor((T-t)/s)){
    a[i+1] <- (  ((-1)^i) * factorial(t)/( factorial(t-i)*factorial(i) ) * factorial(T-s*i-1)/( factorial(T-s*i-t)*factorial(t-1) )  )
    b<-cumsum(a)
    
  }
  for(i in 0:floor((H-l)/s)){
    r[i+1] <- (  ((-1)^i) * factorial(l)/( factorial(l-i)*factorial(i) ) * factorial(H-s*i-1)/( factorial(H-s*i-l)*factorial(l-1) )  )
    c<-cumsum(l)
  }
  
  return (tail(b-((t*(t-1))/2)*c,n=1))
  
  
}
```

It calculates the total number of combinations leading to a given total if using a defined number of dice "t". The dice have 5 sides from two to six.

I want to create a matrix showing the number of combination for each total given a number of dice.

*exemple: For the total of 10, i would find at any number of given 2-6 dices the total number of combinations leading to it.
For 3 it's 15 combinations, for two it's 3 and so on.
I want this informations displayed in a matrix for all potential values up to 20 dices.*

**I have tried :**

```
for(i in 1:t) {
  
    for(j in 1:6*t) {
      
      M[j,i]<-combination(i,6,j)

    }
  
return(M)
  
}
}
```

I'm a bit of a newby and even if i understand (i think) why it doesn't work, i don't know how to make it work :(

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: One newby note: set `t = 3` and compare `1:6*t` and `1:(6*t)` in your R console. `:` is surprising high on the order of operations. Also `for` loops don't `return()` anything. Get rid of your `return(M)`. And it seems like you have an extra `}` in the for loop. With those changes, it might work. (Assuming `combination` works well... have you tested it?)

Comment: Also one style recommendation: `T` and `F` are built-in values short for `TRUE` and `FALSE`. It's possible to redefine them, but most people find it very confusing, and strongly recommend not using `T` or `F` as user-defined variables.

Comment: If you need more help than that, then please be more specific. What does "doesn't work" mean? Is there an error? If so, what is it? Or is there an unexpected result? Or something else? What value of `t` are you using? You say *"even if i understand (i think) why it doesn't work"* -- what is your understanding?